# Why `Loop` write more than once

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, foreach

I try to create a `guessed` with `javascript` and this is the code:

```
<script>
function makeid(len)
{
    var text = "";
    //var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var possible = "abc";

    for( var i=0; i < len; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}
 ////////////////////////////////////////////




var password = 'abc';
var correctGuess = false
var guess; 

do {
    document.write(makeid(3) + "<br>");
    guess = makeid(3);
  if (guess === password) {
    correctGuess = true;
  }
} while ( ! correctGuess ) 
  document.write("You know the secret password. Welcome.");

</script>
```

But unfortunately the result is repeated more than once :
The result:

> abb baa `aac` cba cbb aba bbb `aac` acb cba ccc bab caa bab ccc `aac` ccb
>   aba abc bac cbb

This slows down the program,, how disband this problem
Is there a solution?
thank you

Comment: The makeid in document.write line will not match the guess...

Comment: I have posted an answer, feel free to check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to not check the same password twice, generating random guesses is obviously not the right way to go. As klumme mentioned, storing an array of previous guesses would only increase time and space complexity, so that is also out. What you will have to do is use a brute force method, that is, trying every combination of characters until you get the correct answer. Here's how you can implement it:

**NOTE:** Keep in mind that brute force algorithms are typically pretty inefficient, and if you use the full alphanumeric string that you have in your original code to brute force passwords of more than 3-4 characters, it will take a significant amount of time (especially in a browser). JavaScript, by nature, is not an extremely powerful number crunching language - so this answer is more for the idea of it, than for use in most real-world environments.

```js
function guesser(len) {
  var arr = Array.apply(null, Array(len));
  var propIndex = -1;
  var indexes = arr.reduce(function(total, curr) {
    propIndex++;
    total[propIndex] = 0;
    return total;
  }, {});
  var lastGuess = arr.map(function() {
    return possible[possible.length - 1];
  }).join("");
  var guess = "";
  var found = false;
  while (guess !== lastGuess) {
    guess = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < propIndex; i++) {
      // if on last char, reset to 0 and increment previous index start position
      if (indexes[propIndex - i] >= possible.length) {
        indexes[propIndex - i - 1]++;
        indexes[propIndex - i] = 0;
      }
    }
    for (var i in indexes) {
      guess += possible[indexes[i]];
    }

    document.write(guess + "<br/>");
    if (guess === password) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
    // increment last char
    indexes[propIndex]++;
  }
  if (found) {
    document.write("You know the secret password. Welcome.");
  } else {
    document.write("Sorry, you do not know the secret password.");
  }
}


var password = 'dcd';
var possible = "abcd";
guesser(password.length);
```

Comment: you know what ,, you are great :)
..
thanks to you and `klumme` , and `kind user` for his try

Comment: ok sorry bro ,,
one another thing about NOTE
.. is there mmm  simple browser for this things `on example` ?

Comment: @عبدالرحمنالذهبي I'm not understanding your question - could you try to rephrase it?

Comment: I mean, what about solution it stopped if there are more than 4 characters in browsers .. do you have an idea ?

Comment: @عبدالرحمنالذهبي Unfortunately, that's out of my area of expertise. I wish I knew more about cracking algorithms, but I have not studied them very extensively. That may be a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I just wonder if it's even more efficient than the previous solution. It's like a mass of loops here.

Comment: @Kinduser It is true that I have do have more total loop iterations, however, I have significantly fewer function calls. # of iterations for password `dcd`, possibilities: `a,b,c,d` (me: 360, klumme: 77), # of function calls for same criteria: (me: 7, klumme: 239). I don't have the exact numbers, but I know function calls are far more expensive than loop iterations - although, you raise a good point, and it would be awesome if someone could perf these two algorithms to compare efficiency.

Comment: @mhodges Ok my friend,, I'll put the question in the `Code Review` and teach you the latest news `:D`

Comment: @mhodges Code Review only allows questions from the author or maintainer of the code. You may post a question there, but عبدالرحمنالذهبي cannot.

Comment: @200_success Aren't all answers on SO subject to the CC licence? If the OP decides to adopt my answer into their production code, they are now the maintainer of that code. I will not be maintaining the code provided in this answer. The OP would not be asking on behalf of anyone other than themselves - I would see that as being within the guidelines, wouldn't it?

Comment: [It's not just a matter of licensing.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1294/9357) We require the poster to understand the code and be able to explain the design decisions that went into it. Furthermore, we can't critique other people's code for moral reasons.

Comment: @200_success Fair enough. I stand corrected. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, the problem is that the random password function ("makeid") may return the same password several times. This is no surprise, there's no reason for the function to know which passwords have been tried already. You could keep track of already tried passwords and not try one if it has been tried before (as in Kind user's answer), but in this case it probably wouldn't speed up the program.

A better approach would probably be to iterate through the possible passwords systematically instead of randomly. For example, try "aaa" first, then "aab", "aac" "aba" and so on.

Here is something I came up with -- it's probably not very fast. I use an array of indices into the "possible" string until actually trying the password, because I don't wan't to mess around with indexOf() on the way.

```
const correctPassword = 'abc';
const possible = 'abc';
const maxIndex = possible.length - 1;

function next(previous) {
    var i = previous.length - 1;
    while (previous[i] === maxIndex) {
        previous[i] = 0;
        i--;
        // All passwords have been tried.
        if (i < 0) {
            return [];
        }
    }
    previous[i]++;
    return previous;
}

var current = Array(3).fill(0);
var currentPassword;

while (current.length != 0) {
    currentPassword = current.map(function (i) {
        return possible[i];
    }).join('');
    document.write(currentPassword + '<br>');
    if (currentPassword === correctPassword) {
        document.write('You know the secret password. Welcome.');
        break;
    }
    current = next(current);
}
```

Comment: You have exactly the right idea, put it into code and I will upvote

Comment: If you will provide an algorithm which solves the problem in the same way you have written it, I will upvote your answer even twice.

Comment: Great idea,, Can you explain the idea programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, store the results inside an array. Secondly, add a following condition: `if (arr.indexOf(guess) == -1)` - if the guessed number is already in the array - skip it.

```js
function makeid(len) {
  var text = "";
  //var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  var possible = "abc";

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
}

var password = 'abc';
var correctGuess = false;
var guess;
var arr = [];

while (!correctGuess) {
  guess = makeid(3);
  if (arr.indexOf(guess) == -1) {
    arr.push(guess)
    if (guess === password) {
      correctGuess = true;
    }
  }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: The OP was asking to remove duplicate password guesses. For example, they want to prevent checking for "aab" more than once.

Comment: @mhodges I was editing my post while you have written it, mate.

Comment: This doesn't make the algorithm any more efficient..it still generates duplicate values and still does a comparison on the duplicate value. In fact, checking `indexOf` may actually be significantly slower than just doing a straight up comparison with the password. Also, storing an array of previous guesses chews up memory, which isn't a huge issue if the possible chars are only `a, b, c`, but when you do alphanumeric, you will probably run the browser out of memory with your array of guesses.

Comment: @mhodges I know that talk and downvoting is cheap, but if you care, provide more efficient way to solve it.

Comment: The tooltip on the downvote button says "This answer is not useful". Your answer is exactly that -- it is less efficient and more memory intensive than the OP's original code. I am working on a solution, but it takes time. I don't want to haphazardly post an answer that is not useful.

Comment: @mhodges With all respect, I wouldn't say that my answer *is bad*. Maybe it doesn't clearly improves the performance of OP code, but bad is lil bit too harsh imo. Let's look at that case objectively, klumme solution is great, aswell as complicated. I fully support him and you and if you will provide another solution, with clearly better performance, I swear I will delete my answer by myself.

Comment: "Doesn't clearly improve the performance".. no, it pretty clearly **worsens** the performance. From both a time and space complexity standpoint. Are you telling me that you would use this code yourself in production to solve this issue? C'mon man.. you and I both know this is not a good answer. Why are you holding on to this so much? It's not an indictment of you personally -- we all overlook things sometimes, but it's important to point it out and not spread it to the community.

Comment: @mhodges thanks bro ,,
If you have another good solution .. :)
We will be waiting for you ^ _ ^

Comment: I have posted an answer - feel free to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I got interested in this question and decided to use it as an opportunity to learn more about generators. Note: Uses ES6 syntax, so not necessarily compatible with all platforms.

I wouldn't necessarily recommend this over the other approaches already put in place, but it might be a good future reference.

```
/**
 * Invoke `callback` with every possible combination of `elements` up to length of `length`, until `callback` returns `true`
 * @param elements an array of elements to be passed to `callback`
 * @param length the maximum number of elements to pass to `callback`
 * @param callback a function taking an array of elements, that returns a boolean
 * @returns the first combination of elements for which `callback(combination)` returns `true`. Returns undefined if no combination up to the specified `length` returns `true`.
 */
const combineAndCall = (elements = [], length = 0, callback) => {
  const it = permuteIterator(elements, length);

  for (const el of it) {
    if (callback(el)) {
      return el;
    }
  }
};

/**
 * Returns a generator that returns permutations, with repeated elements, of an array. The maximum length of each permutation is `len`
 * @param arr the array to iterate. The first iteration will always be the empty array.
 * 
 * Example:
 * const it = permuteIterator([1,2,3], 2);
 * it.next().value; // []
 * it.next().value; // [1]
 * it.next().value; // [2]
 * it.next().value; // [3]
 * it.next().value; // [1,1]
 * it.next().value; // [1,2]
 * it.next().value; // [1,3]
 * it.next().value; // [2,1]
 * it.next().value; // [2,2]
 * ...
 * it.next().value; // [3,3]
 * 
 * @len the maximum length of each permutation
 * @returns a generator that iterates the array
 */
function *permuteIterator(arr, len) {
  let current = [];

  function *helper(current, arr, len) {
    if (current.length >= len) {
      yield current;
    } else {
      for (const el of arr) {
        yield* helper([...current, el], arr, len);
      }
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
    yield* helper([], arr, i);
  }
}

/**
 * Validates a password
 * @param elements an array of strings (usually single characters) to combine into a a single string, and compare against the password
 * @returns true if the string resulting from `elements.join("")` exactly equals the real password, false otherwise
 */
const passwordValidator = (elements) => {
  const guess = elements.join("");
  //console.log("validating:", guess);
  return guess === "abc";
};

const alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
//const alphabet = "abc";
const elements = alphabet.split("");
const guessedPassword = combineAndCall(elements, 3, passwordValidator);

if (guessedPassword) {
  console.log(`You know the secret password '${guessedPassword.join("")}'. Welcome.`);
} else {
  console.log("You don't know the secret password. Rejected.");
}
```